# Why do I get a 400 when uploading a file with boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm attempting to upload a file to `boto`,

```
import io

from boto.s3 import connection
from boto.s3 import key

conn = connection.S3Connection()
bucket = conn.get_bucket('my-bucket')

my_key = key.Key(bucket, 'asdf')

d = b'this is a test....\n' * 512000
f = io.BytesIO(d)

my_key.send_file(f, size=4*1024)
```

However, this results in:

```
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>BadRequest</Code><Message>An error occurred when parsing the HTTP request.</Message><RequestId>[hex request ID]</RequestId><HostId>[giant piece of base64]</HostId></Error>
```

**Why is this request failing?**

(note: the whole reason I'm using [`send_file`](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.send_file) here is because `open` apparently only supports reading…)

Comment: What happens if you do ``my_key.set_contents_from_file(f)``.  Do you get the same error?

Comment: @garnaat The call succeeds; part of the point of this is to ensure `boto` doesn't read the entire file into memory: if I add the size argument, `set_contents_from_file` only reads the first `size` bytes. (Which is what the docs say that function will do, but is not what I want.)

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is true streaming but unfortunately S3 does not support that.  At least not yet.

Comment: @garnaat How is that? Isn't an S3 upload just a PUT request, the body of which should certainly be streamable?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by streamable.  You have to know the size of the body up front because you need to supply a ``Content-Length`` header.  So, it's not chunked transfer encoding.  But you can certainly send the data incrementally as long as you don't take so long that the connection times out.  Boto itself reads files in chunks and sends one chunk at a time to avoid having to read large files into memory before sending.

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth, replacing `send_file()` with `set_contents_from_file()` worked for me (I had the same error).